# libgdx not launching in android launcher Android Studios

Tags: java, android, libgdx, runtime-error

I have started learning developing games on android with libgdx .
When i run the game on desktop it runs fine but when i try to run it on android it is crashing .
This is the error i get :

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (com/kokolight/game/states/GameOverState) does not match path (com/kokolight/game/States/GameOverState.class)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:520)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
    ... 12 more
1 error; aborting


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

What more information should i provide to you guys for helping me solve that problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: from this line `(com/kokolight/game/states/GameOverState) does not match path (com/kokolight/game/States/GameOverState.class)` it seems that you've moved `GameOverState` to package `States`. So, try to rebuild your Android project

Comment: Thanks so much dude!!!! it worked like a charm!

Comment: Glad to hear that :) I posted it as an answer.

Comment: please don't forget to mark an answer as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this line `(com/kokolight/game/states/GameOverState) does not match path (com/kokolight/game/States/GameOverState.class)` it seems that you've moved `GameOverState` to package `States`. So, try to rebuild your Android project